# Obtain all functions in a file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, function, node.js

I have some functions inside a file. I'm trying to obtain all functions in that file, from within that file. Normally, all functions are in the `window` object, but I'm using Node.js, which does not seem to have a `window` object.

Say I have something along the lines of the following in a file:

```
function foo() {}
function bar() {}
```

then:

1. Are the functions saved in some global object?
2. If not, how can I access these functions without knowing their names? Can I iterate through all existing functions and obtain them in such a way?

Comment: Have you tried `this`? (The global `this`, not inside an instantiated class)

Comment: @brettz9: I tried your suggestion: `function foo(){};console.log(this.foo)` but it returns `undefined` - or is this not what you mean?

Comment: That was my guess--surprised it doesn't work...Googling got me me this: "process is no longer the global object. GLOBAL is."

Comment: @brettz9: `this.foo`, `global.foo`, `process.foo` are all undefined unfortunately...

Comment: If helpful, there is also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133114/global-object-in-node-js and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133149/modifying-global-object-in-node-js

Comment: Since JS is case sensitive, and [some pages](http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-nodejs) say it is GLOBAL not global, you might try that too. Or, per one comment, maybe it is just a problem in node-repl environment. Other than that, I'm out of guesses. :)

Comment: [Other people](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.javascript.nodejs/21513) have gotten `this` working with some version or other, though I know that might not help in your case.

Comment: @brettz9: No luck with `GLOBAL`, and it's not node-repl but just `node.exe` executed with a `.js` file.

Comment: @pimvdb try `module.foo`

Comment: @Raynos: I cannot get your suggestion working either I'm afraid: `function foo(){};console.log(module.foo);` returns `undefined` as well.

Comment: @pimvdb your issue might be function declarations. Try `var foo = 42;console.log(module.foo);`

Comment: @Raynos: Again `undefined`, even with just a number.

Comment: Just tested this myself in 0.4.8. You just can't do this anymore. @pimvdb There are extensions of nodejs you could install that would allow you to do this. But this basically means using C++ to extend javascript as a language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a common pattern

```
var foo = exports.foo = function() {
    // ...
}
```

This way its written to `exports` and you can access it locally as `foo`

Answer (score 1):

You want to get access to the current scope object but it's impossible in JavaScript.

Comment: I might be wrong but in a browser I can access `window` in this case. Is this not available in Node.js at all?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133114/global-object-in-node-js

Comment: And actually what you want to do is against all the rules, I even heard somewhere people are killed for such things, even for attempts...:) P.S.: I mean polluting of the global scope.

Comment: @bjornd: What I understand from your link is that the functions are 'global on their own', so no solution in that case, is that correct?

Comment: Why not to assign them to the module.exports right when you define them?

Comment: @bjornd: Because I have to call them like `exports.foo` at all times, when used inside the file itself.

Comment: @pimvdb `var foo = exports.foo = function() { };`

Comment: @Raynos: That's a possibility, thanks. However, is it correct that I cannot just code `function foo(){}` and add some code at the end to put all functions into `exports`?

Comment: @pimvdb Yes that is correct. In current versions of node.js you cannot do this. You do not have access to the [[Scope]] object.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions are wrapped in a closure. Remember, node wraps file modules within something like this

```
var module = { exports: {}};
(function(module, exports){
    // your file module content
})(module, module.exports);
```

They are locals. Assign functions to an object, `exports` or `global` to enumerate them.