# How can I declare a global require in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [node.js global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447771/node-js-global-variables)

How can i include a file or a script in node js, that i can access it global. I would like to extend the standard Array Object with some functions, but i dont like to do this in app.js and wenn i declare it in a module, it is not possible to access it global.

Is there a possibility with a other command to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [node.js global variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447771/node-js-global-variables) see also [Global variables for node.js standard modules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140661/global-variables-for-node-js-standard-modules)

Comment: thank you for your answer. it helped me to find the solution: i can do easy a global include. just dont use the module.exports. So i can write all the extending functions for  the Array Object.