# Expressjs - global objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an app written using express with connections to db, logger and other long living objects that requires to be open and accessed by multiple js files.

What are some of the techniques I could use to make the object "global" with minimal overhead/maintanence?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you could put it in a `foo.js` file and use `require('foo.js')` to load it. This object is created only one according to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179109/singleton-pattern-in-nodejs-is-it-needed)

Answer (score 0):

Define like this
//global.js

```
module.export = function(){


    //define your global object and function here.
}
```

and call
 `require('global.js')` in your script where you want