# Updating global variables with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm beginner to NodeJS, so I'm not entirely sure what the best method to achieve this would be. Basically I want to create a global variable with a string, for instance 'USD', that would get updated whenever my 'set currency' event is fired. I want it to remain that way until the event is called again.

I am using EventEmitter to fire off some events, in one of my files I have the following.

```
 var event = require('./events');

  if (msg.content.includes('!currency set currency')) {
    split = msg.content.split(' ');
    event.emit('setCurrency', split[3])
  }
```

And then inside the events file I'm doing something like the following.

```
var exchangePref;

var event = new events.EventEmitter();


event.on('setExchange', (exchange) => {
   exchangePref = exchange;
   return exchangePref;
});

modules.exports = event;
```

I understand that re-writing the variable inside a callback isn't going to do what I need it to do, but I'm quite lost with how to achieve what I need it to do due to the `modules.exports = event` part at the bottom, the calling function simply never gets the data. I've played around with creating a constructor, but even still I couldn't get it to work.

Any suggestions/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use event emitter for this. Instead create a module along the lines of:

```
var exchangePrefs = { currency: "JPY" };
module.exports = { 
    setCurrency : function(newVal){ exchangePrefs.currency = newVal; },
    getCurrency : function(){ return exchangePrefs.currency; }
};
```

Then in your various other modules you just:

```
require('./mymodule').setCurrency('USD');
```

and somewhere else

```
var currency = require('./mymodule').getCurrency();
```

I'm sure it can be made prettier, but I think you get the point. For almost all intents and purposes modules work like singletons. There are some gotchas, but nothing you'll run into too often. ([Singleton pattern in nodejs - is it needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179109/singleton-pattern-in-nodejs-is-it-needed))

Personally I'd use some sort of data persistence in the exchangePref-module just for peace of mind. Like redis, or saving to a json-file.

Comment: This looks like it will set me on the right path, appreciated!