# Electron - IPC changes the object

Tags: node.js, singleton, electron, ipc

In my Electron project, I'm trying to make a module singleton by setting it as a global. Since I use `jquery` in this module, I import it in the renderer process and then send it to the main via ipc and set it as global there. Here is related part of my code:

main.js:

```
ipcMain.on( "setGlobal", ( event, global_var) => {
  global[global_var[0]] = global_var[1];
  console.log(global_var);
  event.returnValue = 1;
} );
```

renderer.js:

```
const favourites = require("./components/favourites");

console.log(favourites);

ipcRenderer.sendSync("setGlobal", ["favourites", favourites]);

console.log(remote.getGlobal("favourites"));
```

The outputs of `console.log`s in the renderer process are in the image below:

[image: renderer output]

And the output of the main process is:

```
[ 'favourites', { favourites: [] } ]
```

As you see, the object (module) I sent from the ipcRenderer is changed in the ipcMain, it lost its `add` and `init` functions. Do you have any idea what is the reason of this behavior and how to fix it?

**PS: To be sure, I tested it with a simple objects that contains functions instead of `require("favourites")`. They are also behaving in the same way. I did a workaround by using only the entities as global and passing them to all of the functions as arguments. However, it's not a good way in sense of code readability.**

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use IPC like that. As noted in docs (eg. [`sendSync`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendsyncchannel-arg1-arg2-))

> Send a message to the main process synchronously via channel, you can also send arbitrary arguments. Arguments will be serialized in JSON internally and hence no functions or prototype chain will be included.

Your functions are simply not making it to main process.

---

For making a module singleton you should just use the singleton pattern in your module, and use `require` in main process and `remote.require` in renderer. Since require using cache (at least by default), the same module should be returned. (more or less. Further reading can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13179109/2550156))

For example if you export a class:

```js
let _instance = null
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    if (_instance === null) _instance = this
    return _instance
  }
  ...
}
module.exports = MyClass
```

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer! The only problem is that I can't import my module into the main process because it requires `jQuery` and importing it produces error. Thus, I should import it in the renderer.

Answer (score -1):

After @pergy's answer, I decided to drop IPC and use only the globals. So, here is the workaround I find:

main process:

```
global.provider = {};
```

renderer process:

```
const favourites = require("./components/favourites");
remote.getGlobal("provider").favourites = favourites;
```

other modules:

```
const favourites = remote.getGlobal("provider").favourites;
```