# Do the NPM modules in my node app share dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have an app that I'm working on that is three separate modules. All three modules will be packaged separately and stored in a private NPM repository. So each module will have it's own `index.js`, `package.json`, etc.

`Module A` depends on `Module B` and `Module C`. `Module B` depends on `Module C`.

[image: Dependency Chart]

Because `Module A` and `Module B` both have a dependency on `Module C`, will they share the dependency?

For instance, let's say that `Module C` has a `singleton.js` file that returns a `singleton`.

**singleton.js**

```
class MyClass {

}

const instance = new MyClass();

module.exports = instance;
```

And then the **index.js** for `Module C` exports that as well.

```
const myClassSingleton = require('./lib/singleton.js')

module.exports = myClassSingleton;
```

If both `Module A` and `Module B` `require` `Module C`

```
const moduleC = require('module-c');
```

Are they both sharing that same instance of that `Singleton`?

Comment: Depends on the resolved path of the files being required. If they have each have their own copy of `module-c` in their own `node_modules` directory, then no. So it's not guaranteed, and will be on the whim of the package manager you use. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179109/singleton-pattern-in-nodejs-is-it-needed

Comment: I use it when I am in control of the require path, so inside a single app/module.

Comment: Across modules it should be less troublesome if you setup the code to inject the shared instance at initialisation.

Comment: Also tools like babel will add another layer of indirection/complexity to the answer.

Comment: @Matt, thanks. I'm trying to read more into this. I noticed sometimes that my modules have their own `node_modules` while other times they seem to just share the top level `node_modules` folder. It seems like it's dependent on that, as you suggest. How does NPM/Node determine if they will have their own `node_modules` folder or share the top level one? Does it have to do with versioning?

Comment: Versioning definitely requires different files, but it's changed so much over npm versions and yarn I wouldn't try to answer. There's always going to be some caveat with npm. If you can supply a bit more detail of what your doing between A/B/C people will probably be able to provide an alternative to using the module based singleton.