# Default binding of `this` is different from Chrome browser and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, scope, v8

I was reading [Chapter 2: `this` All Makes Sense Now!](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md) from [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS), and decided to do this experiment.

I have this simple enough script `foo.js`:

```
var a = 'foo';
var output;

// lets find a way to output strings in both
// Chrome and Node.js
if (typeof alert === 'undefined') {
    output = console.log;
} else {
    output = alert;
}

function getA() {
    return this.a;
}

var foo = getA();
output(foo);
```

I am expecting following things when `getA()` is called:

1. Since the call site of `getA` is in global scope, `getA()` will be bound to global object.
2. Since `var a` is declared in global scope, I take it that global object will have a property named `a`, and this property is same as the variable `a`.
3. Because of that, I expect `this.a` to refer to variable `a`.
4. Thus I expect `output(foo)` to print the string `foo`.

However, when run in Node.js (non-strict mode), this is the output:

```
$ node foo.js
undefined
```

Then I included the same script in a simple HTML page, and loaded it in chrome.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="foo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Chrome `alert`s the string `foo`, just as expected.

Why does the output of Chrome differ from Node.js?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Since the call site of getA is in global scope, getA() will be bound to global object.

no, that's not true for node - your script is wrapped into a function [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.33-release/src/node.js#L883-L885) so your example is actually this code:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
  var a = 'foo';
  var output;

  // lets find a way to output strings in both
  // Chrome and Node.js
  if (typeof alert === 'undefined') {
    output = console.log;
  } else {
    output = alert;
  }

  function getA() {
    return this.a;
  }

  var foo = getA();
  output(foo);
})(exports, require, module, 'file.js', '/dir/name');
```

Answer (score 15):

> Since the call site of getA is in global scope, getA() will be bound to global object.

This is a misunderstanding of the `this` binding rules from my book. The call site's **location** (aka "in global scope") is entirely irrelevant. It's the manner in which the call is made, and only that.

It's not **where** `getA()` happens that matters, but that `getA()` is a plain normal function call. **THAT** is what determines that you'll get the global object bound to the `this` for that call.

The other answers here are correct... the scope your node main program runs in is actually a module (function wrapped), not a real global scope.

Answer (score 8):

NodeJS behaves differently than browsers. The top-level scope is not the global scope, it's the scope within that file or module. Drop the "var" and your code will work (a will become truly global) in a node environment and it will console.log the string 'foo'.

See the following page for a full reference: http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html

OR

[How to use global variable in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987444/how-to-use-global-variable-in-node-js/27031734#27031734)

Comment: So why does NodeJS behave differently than browser in this scenario? Yes I could drop `var` and the example will work. But I'm not interested in making globals in Node.js. I want to understand how the binding of `this` works here. What exactly is bound to `this` in this example?

Comment: In your browser, "this" is the window object.  In node, it is an object called "global".  Try console.log(this); inside your getA() method, and compare this to console.log(this) in Chrome's console.  You will notice they are both top level objects that give you javascript primitive & object types such as ArrayBuffer, setTimeout, setInterval.  You could also define a global object in node by doing "global.name_of_var".

Comment: See lines 788-795 in node's source code to see exactly what it's doing.  It uses a method called NativeModule.wrap() around your source code upon compilation.  https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node.js#L788

Comment: @Krumia `this` is global object. Its just that `a` is tied locally to foo.js and not to global.