# Adding properties to a nested interface in node.js

Tags: node.js, oop, typescript, interface, partial-classes

In a file named 'some-file.ts' I want to do this:

```
global.someProp  = someVar;
```

while `global` is a predefined object of type `NodeJS.Global` which is defined in node.d.ts.

How can I make this interface partial?

I've tried all of the following to no avail:

```
interface Global {
        someProp: string;
    }

global.someProp  = someVar;



interface NodeJS.Global {
        someProp: string;
    }

global.someProp  = someVar;



namespace NodeJS{
    interface Global {
        someProp: string;
    }
}

global.someProp  = someVar;
```

I keep getting:

> TS339: Property 'someProp' does not exist on type 'Global'

How can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use global variable in node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987444/how-to-use-global-variable-in-node-js)

Comment: @SteevePitis no! It's a completely different question.

Comment: Then try to explain your goal in a different way because I've never seen those keyword in js `namespace` & `interface`

Comment: @SteevePitis my question is completely about TypeScript and using partial interface which is a feature of TypeScript. The question you referred is not about TypeScript at all!

Comment: Ok, say this in your title ;)

Comment: @SteevePitis my question is about TypeScript, not JavsScript.

Comment: @SteevePitis instead of changing the title, Endless has removed the 'javascript' tag, so it's clear now. Thank you.

Comment: Btw since your are running this on NodeJS and TypeScript is only sugar in front of Javascript ... the answer will probably not be so far ...

Comment: @Steeve Pitis don't jinx! It's been 37 hours and no answers yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it. I had to use the keyword 'declare' as follows:

```
declare namespace NodeJS{
    interface Global {
        base_dir: string;
    }
}
```