# NodeJS - Get variable from another file without redefining it each call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, export, global-variables

So I have 2 files a mapgen.js and a main.js. In mapgen.js there is a function that generates a giant 2d array. I want to use this aray in main.js but don't want the function that generates the map to run everytime its 'required' in main.js. I also want to be able to edit the map array eventually.

Example: (not real code just wrote some crap to show what the issue is)

mapgen.js:

```
var map;
function mapGen(){
    //make the map here
      this function takes like 2 seconds and some decent CPU power, so 
      don't want it to ever run more than once per server launch
    map = map contents!
}
```

main.js

```
var map = require mapgen.js;
console.log(map.map);
//start using map variable defined earlier, but want to use it without
  having to the run the big funciton again, since it's already defined.
```

I know i have to module.exports somewhere but I dont think that will solve my problem still. I would write it to a file but is that not much slower to read and edit than keeping it in the ram? Previously I had gotten past this by keeping everything in 1 file but now I need to clean it all up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requiring the module won't automatically invoke the function. You can do that in the main.js file.

#### mapgen.js

```
module.exports = function mapGen() {
  return [/* hundreds of items here. */];
};
```

#### main.js

```
// Require the module that constructs the array.
const mapGen = require('./mapgen');

// Construct the array by invoking the mapGen function and 
// store a reference to it in 'map'.
const map = mapGen(); // `map` is now a reference to the returned array.
// Do whatever you want with 'map'.
console.log(map[0]); // Logs the first element.
```

Comment: Well main.js will be run a bunch of times, its not a one time thing, so everytime main is run again it will run the mapgen function again, and thats not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but if you put one condition in mapgen.js that don't work ?

```
var map;
function mapGen(){
    if(!map){
       //your code here
       map = map contents!
    }
}
```

Combine that with global variable and/or module.exports  See 
[How to use global variable in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987444/how-to-use-global-variable-in-node-js)

Comment: That could work, but when I refrence it from another file, my issue is that it says map is null since its defined as null on line 1, and not filled until later.