# (Node.js) How can I save in a global variable my converted .JSON file?

Tags: node.js, json, csv

I'm a beginners with Node.JS... I created a .Json file from a .csv with the 'csvtojson module' but I can't find out how save the Json in a global variable in order to use it... Could someone help me?

```
const CSVToJSON = require('csvtojson');
const fs = require('fs');

// convert users.csv file to JSON array
CSVToJSON().fromFile('flyers_data.csv')
    .then( flyers_data => {
        

        console.log(flyers_data);
    }).catch(err => {
        // log error if any
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use global variable in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987444/how-to-use-global-variable-in-node-js)

Comment: Why you need a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

in nodejs you can require .json file directly to use :

```
// foo.json


{
   "bar":"buzz"
}
```

in js:

```
let fooFile =  require("/path/to/foo.json")


console.log(fooFile)
console.log(foorFile.bar)
```