# How can I detect all dependencies of a function in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to give a broad picture of my problem. I need to write a program with Node.js that should be able to detect all dependencies a function.

E.g.

```
function a() {
   //do something
   b();
};

function b() {
  console.log("Hey, This is b");
};
```

At the example above I need to have an JSON like this:

```
{
    "a": {
        dependencies: ["b"],
        range: [1, 4]
    },
    "b": {
        dependencies: [],
        range: [5, 8]
    }
}
```

In the `dependencies` property I need to have an array of functions that called inside the function, and by `range` I mean the line range of function definition.

I need a solution to achieve this goal. Are there any tools or plugins for Node.js?

Comment: How about something like `function b() { function a() {} } function a() {}` ? how would you like that represented? I'm trying to mock something up using [acorn](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/acorn/), and the question seems a bit optimistic with regard to code simplicity.

Comment: What you want to do isn't really reasonable.  How do you expect to handle anonymous functions which don't exist until runtime?  What about functions created purely programmatically (such as with `eval()`)?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

(I apologise in advance: I usually try and make my answers humorous to ease the reader through them, but I couldn't successfully do so in this case. Consider that a double apology for the length of this answer.)

### 0. TL;DR (for "normal people") of the problem

This is not an easy problem. Instead of solving it in full, we will limit its scope - we will only solve the portion of the problem we care about. We will do so by parsing the input with a JavaScript parser and going over it with a simple [recurive-descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) algorithm. Our algorithm will analyse the program's scope and correctly identify function calls.

All the rest is just filling in the blanks! The result is at the bottom of the answer, so I recommend you grab to the [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905249/how-can-i-detect-all-dependencies-of-a-function-in-node-js/18004786#comment26329922_18004786) if you don't want to read through.

### 1. Limiting the problem

As [Benjamin Gruenbaum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17905485/1348195) says, this is a very, very hard problem because of JavaScript's dynamic nature. However, what if instead of making a solution which'll work for 100% of programs, we instead do it for a subset of programs, if we limit ourselves to handle certain things?

The most important limitation:

- **No `eval`**. If we include `eval`, it's a spiral into chaos. This is because eval let's you use arbitrary strings which makes tracking dependencies impossible without checking every possible input. In NodeJS there are no `document.write`s and `setTimeout` only accepts a function so we don't have to worry about those. However, we also disallow the [vm module](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/vm.html).

The following limitations are to ease the process. They may be solvable, but solving them is out of scope for this answer:

1. **No dynamic keys** `obj[key]()` it saddens me to introduce this limitation, but it's definitely solvable for some cases (e.g. `key = 'foo'` but not `key = userInput()`)
2. **Variables are not shadows**, no `var self = this`. Definitely solvable with a complete scope parser.
3. **No funky expressions**, e.g. `(a, b)()`

And finally, limitations to the implementation in this answer - either because of complexity constraints or time constraints (but they are very solvable):

4. **No hoisting**, so function declarations won't bob up in the scope.
5. **No object handling**. This sucks, but handling things like `foo.bar()` or `this.foo()` would've at least doubled the program complexity. Put in enough time, and it's very doable.
6. **Only function scope is honored**. There're ways in JavaScript to define scopes other than functions (the `with` statement, `catch` blocks). We don't deal with them.

In this answer, I'll outline (and provide) a proof-of-concept parser.

### 2. Approaching the problem

Given a program, how can we decipher its function dependencies?

```
//A. just a global function
globalFunction();
//B. a function within a function
var outer = function () {
    function foo () {}
    foo();
};
//C. calling a function within itself
var outer = function inner () {
    inner();
};
//D. disambiguating between two identically named functions
function foo () {
    var foo = function () {};
    foo();
}
foo();
```

In order to understand a program, we need to break its code apart, we need to understand its semantics: we need a parser. I've chosen [acorn](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/acorn/) because I've never used it and heard good praise. I suggest you play with it a bit, see what programs look like in [SpiderMonkeys's AST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API#Node_objects).

Now that we have a magical parser which transforms JavaScript into an AST (an [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)), how will we logically handle finding dependencies? We'll need do two things:

1. Build scopes correctly
2. Understand which function a function call refers to.

We can see why example D above can be ambiguous: There are two functions called `foo`, how can we know which one `foo()` means? That's why we need to implement scoping.

### 3. Solving the problem

Since the solution is in two parts, let's solve it that way. Beginning from the biggest problem:

#### 3.1. Scoping

So...we have an AST. It has a bunch of nodes. How do we build a scope? Well, we only care about function scope. That eases the process, as we know we only have to deal with functions. But before we talk about how to use scopes, let's define the function which makes scopes.

What does a scope have? It's not a complex being: It has a parent scope (or `null` if it's the global scope), and it has the items it contains. We need a way to add things to a scope, and get things from one. Let's do that:

```
var Scope = function (parent) {
    var ret = { items : {}, parent : parent, children : [] };

    ret.get = function (name) {
        if (this.items[name]) {
            return this.items[name];
        }

        if (this.parent) {
            return this.parent.get(name);
        }

        //this is fake, as it also assumes every global reference is legit
        return name;
    };

    ret.add = function (name, val) {
        this.items[name] = val;
    };

    if (parent) {
        parent.children.push(ret);
    }
    return ret;
};
```

As you may have noticed, I'm cheating in two aspects: First, I'm assigning child scopes. That is to make it easier for us measly humans to see that things are working (otherwise, all scoping would be internal, we'd only see the global scope). Second, I'm assuming the global scope contains all - that is, if `foo` isn't defined in any scope, then it must be an existing global variable. That may or may not be desirable.

OK, we have a way to represent scopes. Don't crack open the champagne yet, we still have to actually make them! Let's see how a simple function declaration, `function f(){}` looks like in AST:

```
{
  "type": "Program",
  "start": 0,
  "end": 14,
  "body": [{
    "type": "FunctionDeclaration",
    "start": 0,
    "end": 14,
    "id": {
      "type": "Identifier",
      "start": 9,
      "end": 10,
      "name": "f"
    },
    "params": [],
    "body": {
      "type": "BlockStatement",
      "start": 12,
      "end": 14,
      "body": []
    }
  }]
}
```

That's quite a mouthful, but we can brave through it! The juicy part is this:

```
{
  "type": "FunctionDeclaration",
  "id": {
    "type": "Identifier",
    "name": "f"
  },
  "params": [ ... ],
  "body": { ... }
}
```

We have a `FunctionDeclaration` node with an `id` property. That `id`'s name is our function's name! Let's assume we have a function `walk` which takes care of walking over nodes, and `currentScope` and `currentFuncName` variables, and we've just arrived at parsing our function declaration `node`. How do we do it? Code speaks louder than words:

```
//save our state, so we will return to it after we handled the function
var cachedScope = currentScope,
    cachedName = currentFuncName;

//and now we change the state
currentScope = Scope(cachedScope);
currentFuncName = node.id.name;

//create the bindings in the parent and current scopes
//the following lines have a serious bug, we'll get to it later (remember that
// we have to meet Captain Crunchypants)
cachedScope.add(currentFuncName, currentName);
currentScope.add(currentFuncName, currentName);

//continue with the parsing
walk(node.body);

//and restore the state
currentScope = cachedScope;
currentFuncName = cachedName;
```

But wait, what about function expressions? They behave a bit differently! First and foremost, they don't necessarily have a name, and if they do, it's only visible inside them:

```
var outer = function inner () {
    //outer doesn't exist, inner is visible
};
//outer is visible, inner doesn't exist
```

Let's make another huge assumption that we've dealt with the variable declaration part - we created the proper binding at the parent scope. Then, the logic above for handling functions changes only slightly:

```
...
//and now we change the state
currentScope = Scope(cachedScope);
//we  signify anonymous functions with <anon>, since a function can never be called that
currentFuncName = node.id ? node.id.name : '<anon>';
...
if (node.id) {
    currentScope.add(currentFuncName, currentFuncName);
}
if (node.type === 'FunctionDeclaration') {
    cachedScope.add(currentFuncName, currentFuncName);
}
...
```

And believe it or not, that's more or less the entire scope handling mechanism in the final solution. I expect as you add things like objects it'll get more a bit more complicated, but it not by much.

It's time to meet Captain Crunchpants. The very observant listener will by now have remembered example D. Let's freshen our memory:

```
function foo () {
    function foo () {}
    foo();
}
foo();
```

In parsing that, we need a way to tell the outer `foo` and the inner `foo` apart - otherwise, we won't be able to know which of these `foo` calls, and our dependency finder will be toast. Furthermore, we won't be able to tell them apart in the dependency management - if we just add to the results by function name, we'll get overwriting. In other words, we need an absolute function name.

I chose to represent nesting with separation with a `#` character. The above, then, has a function `foo`, with an inner function `foo#foo`, with a call to `foo#foo` and a call to `foo`. Or, for a less confusing example:

```
var outer = function () {
    function inner () {}
    inner();
};
outer();
```

Has a function `outer` and a function `outer#inner`. There's a call to `outer#inner` and a call to `outer`.

So, let's create this function which takes the previous name, and the current function's name, and mushes them together:

```
function nameToAbsolute (parent, child) {
    //foo + bar => foo#bar
    if (parent) {
        return parent + '#' + name;
    }
    return name;
}
```

And modify our function handling pseudo-code (which is about to come to life! I promise!):

```
...
currentScope = Scope(cachedScope);
var name = node.id ? node.id.name : '<anon>';
currentFuncName = nameToAbsolute(cachedName, name);
...
if (node.id) {
    currentScope.add(name, currentFuncName);
}
if (node.type === 'FunctionDeclaration') {
    cachedScope.add(name, currentFuncName);
}
```

Now we're talking! It's time to move on to actually *doing* something! Maybe I've lied to you all along and I know nothing, maybe I failed miserably and I continued writing until now because I knew nobody will read this far and I'll get many upvotes because it's a long answer!?

HAH! Keep dreming! There's much more to come! I didn't sit on this for a few days for no reason! (As an interesting social experiment, could anyone upvoting comment, saying something around the lines "Captain Crunchpants was happy to see you"?)

On a more serious note, we should **begin making the parser**: What holds our state and walks over nodes. Since we'll have two parsers at the end, scope and dependency, we'll make a "master parser" which calls each one when needed:

```
var parser = {
    results : {},
    state : {},

    parse : function (string) {
        this.freshen();

        var root = acorn.parse(string);
        this.walk(root);

        return this.results;
    },

    freshen : function () {
        this.results = {};
        this.results.deps = {};

        this.state = {};
        this.state.scope = this.results.scope = Scope(null);
        this.state.name = '';
    },

    walk : function (node) {
        //insert logic here
    },

    // ''    =>  'foo'
    // 'bar' =>  'bar#foo'
    nameToAbsolute : function (parent, name) {
        return parent ? parent + '#' + name : name;
    },

    cacheState : function () {
        var subject = this.state;
        return Object.keys( subject ).reduce(reduce, {});

        function reduce (ret, key) {
            ret[key] = subject[key];
            return ret;
        }
    },
    restoreState : function (st) {
        var subject = this.state;

        Object.keys(st).forEach(function (key) {
            subject[key] = st[key];
        });
    }
};
```

That's a bit of cruft, but hopefully it's understandable. We made `state` into an object, and to make it flexible, `cacheState` and `restoreState` are simply cloning/merging.

Now, for our beloved `scopeParser`:

```
var scopeParser = {
    parseFunction : function (func) {
        var startState = parser.cacheState(),

            state = parser.state,
            name = node.id ? node.id.name : '<anon>';

        state.scope = Scope(startState.scope);
        state.name = parser.nameToAbsolute(startState.name, name);

        if (func.id) {
            state.scope.add(name, state.name);
        }
        if (func.type === 'FunctionDeclaration') {
            startState.scope.add(name, state.name);
        }

        this.addParamsToScope(func);
        parser.walk(func.body);

        parser.restoreState(startState);
    }
};
```

The casually observant reader will notice that `parser.walk` is empty. Time to fill 'er up!

```
walk : function (node) {
    var type = node.type;

    //yes, this is tight coupling. I will not apologise.
    if (type === 'FunctionDeclaration' || type === 'FunctionExpression') {
        scopeParser.parseFunction(node)
    }
    else if (node.type === 'ExpressionStatement') {
        this.walk(node.expression);
    }
    //Program, BlockStatement, ...
    else if (node.body && node.body.length) {
        node.body.forEach(this.walk, this);
    }
    else {
        console.log(node, 'pass through');
    }
    //...I'm sorry
}
```

Again, mostly technicalities - to understand these, you need to play with acorn. We want to make sure we iterate and walk into nodes correctly. Expressions Nodes like `(function foo() {})` has an `expression` property we walk over, `BlockStatement` Nodes (e.g. the actual body of a function) and Program Nodes have a `body` array, etc.

Since we have something resembling logic, let's try:

```
> parser.parse('function foo() {}').scope
{ items: { foo: 'foo' },
  parent: null,
  children:
   [ { items: [Object],
       parent: [Circular],
       children: [],
       get: [Function],
       add: [Function] } ],
  get: [Function],
  add: [Function] }
```

Neat! Play around with function declarations and expressions, see that they're nested correctly. We did however forget to include variable declaration:

```
var foo = function () {};
bar = function () {};
```

A good (and fun!) exercise is adding them yourself. But don't worry - they'll be included in the final parser;

Who'd believe!? We're *done* with scopes! D-O-N-E! Let's do a cheer!

Oh oh oh...where did you think you're going!? We only solved part of the problem - we still have to find the dependencies! Or did you forget all about it!? Fine, you can go to the toilet. But it better be #1.

#### 3.2. Dependency

Wow, did you even *remember* we had section numbers? On an unrelated note, when I typed the last sentence, my keyboard made a sound reminiscent of the first note of the Super Mario Theme Song. Which is now stuck in my head.

Ok! So, we have our scopes, we have our function names, it's time to identify function calls! This will not take long. Doing `acorn.parse('foo()')` gives:

```
{
  "type": "Program",
  "body": [{
    "type": "ExpressionStatement",
    "expression": {
      "type": "CallExpression",
      "callee": {
        "type": "Identifier",
        "name": "f"
      },
      "arguments": []
    }
  }]
}
```

So we're looking for a `CallExpression`. But before we go all `walk` over it, let's first review our logic. Given this node, what do we do? How do we add a dependency?

This is not a difficult problem, as we already took care of all the scoping. We add to the dependencies of the containing function (`parser.state.name`) the scope resolution of `callExpression.callee.name`. Sounds simple!

```
var deps = parser.results.deps,
    scope = parser.state.scope,
    context = parser.state.name || '<global>';

if (!deps[context]) {
    deps[context] = [];
}

deps[context].push(scope.get(node.callee.name));
```

There're, once again, a trick with handling the global context. If the current state is nameless, we assume it's the global context and give it a special name `<global>`.

Now that we have that, let's build our `dependencyParser`:

```
var dependencyParser = {
    parseCall : function (node) {
         ...the code above...
    }
};
```

Truly beautiful. We still need to modify `parser.walk` to include `CallExpression`s:

```
walk : function (node) {
    ...
    else if (type === 'CallExpression') {
        dependencyParser.parseCall(node);
    }
}
```

And try it out on example D:

```
> parser.parse('function foo() { var foo = function () {}; foo(); } foo()').deps
{ foo: [ 'foo#foo' ], '<global>': [ 'foo' ] }
```

### 4. Mock the problem

HAHA! IN YOUR FACE, PROBLEM! WOOOOOOOOOOO!

You may commence celebrations. Remove your pants, run around in the city, claim you're the town chicken and burn stray garbage cans (*Zirak and Affiliates in no way support arson of any kind or indecent exposure. Any action taken by oh, say, any reader is not to be blamed upon Zirak and/or Affiliates*).

But seriously now. We solved a very, very limited subset of the problem, and to solve it for a small percentage of real-case scenarios there are a lot of things which have to be done. This is not a discouragement - quite the opposite! I urge you to try and do this. It's fun! (*Zirak and Affiliates are in no way responsible for any mental breakdown as a result from trying to to what was just said*)

Presented here is the source code of the parser, sans any NodeJS specific stuff (i.e. requiring acorn or exposing the parser):

```
var parser = {
    results : {},
    state : {},

    verbose : false,

    parse : function (string) {
        this.freshen();

        var root = acorn.parse(string);
        this.walk(root);

        return this.results;
    },

    freshen : function () {
        this.results = {};
        this.results.deps = {};

        this.state = {};
        this.state.scope = this.results.scope = Scope(null);
        this.state.name = '';
    },

    walk : function (node) {
        var type = node.type;

        //yes, this is tight coupling. I will not apologise.
        if (type === 'FunctionDeclaration' || type === 'FunctionExpression') {
            scopeParser.parseFunction(node)
        }
        else if (type === 'AssignmentExpression') {
            scopeParser.parseBareAssignmentExpression(node);
        }
        else if (type === 'VariableDeclaration') {
            scopeParser.parseVarDeclaration(node);
        }
        else if (type === 'CallExpression') {
            dependencyParser.parseCall(node);
        }
        else if (node.type === 'ExpressionStatement') {
            this.walk(node.expression);
        }
        //Program, BlockStatement, ...
        else if (node.body && node.body.length) {
            node.body.forEach(this.walk, this);
        }
        else if (this.verbose) {
            console.log(node, 'pass through');
        }
        //...I'm sorry
    },

    // ''    =>  'foo'
    // 'bar' =>  'bar#foo'
    nameToAbsolute : function (parent, name) {
        return parent ? parent + '#' + name : name;
    },

    cacheState : function () {
        var subject = this.state;
        return Object.keys( subject ).reduce(reduce, {});

        function reduce (ret, key) {
            ret[key] = subject[key];
            return ret;
        }
    },
    restoreState : function (st) {
        var subject = this.state;

        Object.keys(st).forEach(function (key) {
            subject[key] = st[key];
        });
    }
};

var dependencyParser = {
    //foo()
    //yes. that's all.
    parseCall : function (node) {
        if (parser.verbose) {
            console.log(node, 'parseCall');
        }

        var deps = parser.results.deps,
            scope = parser.state.scope,
            context = parser.state.name || '<global>';

        if (!deps[context]) {
            deps[context] = [];
        }

        deps[context].push(scope.get(node.callee.name));
    }
};

var scopeParser = {
    // We only care about these kinds of tokens:
    // (1) Function declarations
    // function foo () {}
    // (2) Function expressions assigned to variables
    // var foo = function () {};
    // bar = function () {};
    //
    // Do note the following property:
    // var foo = function bar () {
    //     `bar` is visible, `foo` is not
    // };
    // `bar` is not visible, `foo` is

    /*
      function foo () {}
        =>
      {
        "type": 'FunctionDeclaration',
        "id": {
          "type": Identifier,
          "name": 'foo'
        },
        "params": [],
        "body": { ... }
      }

      (function () {})
        =>
      {
        "type": "FunctionExpression",
        "id": null,
        "params": [],
        "body": { ... }
      }
    */
    parseFunction : function (func) {
        if (parser.verbose) {
            console.log(func, 'parseFunction');
        }
        var startState = parser.cacheState(),
            state = parser.state,
            name = this.grabFuncName(func);

        state.scope = Scope(startState.scope);
        state.name = parser.nameToAbsolute(startState.name, name);

        if (func.id) {
            state.scope.add(name, state.name);
        }
        if (func.type === 'FunctionDeclaration') {
            startState.scope.add(name, state.name);
        }

        this.addParamsToScope(func);
        parser.walk(func.body);

        parser.restoreState(startState);
    },

    grabFuncName : function (func) {
        if (func.id) {
            return func.id.name;
        }
        else if (func.type === 'FunctionExpression') {
            return '<anon>';
        }
        else {
            //...this shouldn't happen
            throw new Error(
                'scope.parseFunction encountered an anomalous function: ' +
                    'nameless and is not an expression');
        }
    },

    /*
      [{
        "type": "Identifier",
        "name": "a"
      }, {
        "type": "Identifier",
        "name": "b"
      }, {
        "type": "Identifier",
        "name": "c"
      }]
    */
    addParamsToScope : function (func) {
        var scope = parser.state.scope,
            fullName = parser.state.name;

        func.params.forEach(addParam);

        function addParam (param) {
            var name = param.name;
            scope.add(name, parser.nameToAbsolute(fullName, name));
        }
    },

    parseVarDeclaration : function (tok) {
        if (parser.verbose) {
            console.log(tok, 'parseVarDeclaration');
        }

        tok.declarations.forEach(parseDecl, this);

        function parseDecl (decl) {
            this.parseAssignment(decl.id, decl.init);
        }
    },

    // Lacking a better name, this:
    // foo = function () {}
    // without a `var`, I call a "bare assignment"
    parseBareAssignmentExpression : function (exp) {
        if (parser.verbose) {
            console.log(exp, 'parseBareAssignmentExpression');
        }
        this.parseAssignment(exp.left, exp.right);
    },

    parseAssignment : function (id, value) {
        if (parser.verbose) {
            console.log(id, value, 'parseAssignment');
        }

        if (!value || value.type !== 'FunctionExpression') {
            return;
        }

        var name = id.name,
            val = parser.nameToAbsolute(parser.state.name, name);
        parser.state.scope.add(name, val);

        this.parseFunction(value);
    }
};

var Scope = function (parent) {
    var ret = { items : {}, parent : parent, children : [] };

    ret.get = function (name) {
        if (this.items[name]) {
            return this.items[name];
        }

        if (this.parent) {
            return this.parent.get(name);
        }

        //this is fake, as it also assumes every global reference is legit
        return name;
    };

    ret.add = function (name, val) {
        this.items[name] = val;
    };

    if (parent) {
        parent.children.push(ret);
    }
    return ret;
};
```

Now if you'll excuse me, I need a long shower.

Comment: Wow. You might want to create a small TL;DR section at the top of the answer. You know, for normal people.

Comment: You might want to use [Esprima](http://esprima.org/doc/index.html#ast) to ease the process of building the AST. And to have a full, real AST for your JS code. (without all the constraints of your answer.) Not to mention it's a battle-tested solution.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine The constraints in my answer are purely my own - acorn is a complete (and rather good) js parser. But yes, Esprima is a perfectly viable alternative.

Answer (score 8):

**No.**

Sorry, this is impossible on a pretty theoretical level in a dynamic language with eval. Good IDEs detect basic stuff, but there are some things you simply can't detect very well:

Let's take your simple case:

```
function a() {
   //do something
   b();
};
```

Let's complicate it a bit:

```
function a() {
   //do something
   eval("b();")
};
```

Now we have to detect stuff in strings, let's go one step ahead:

```
function a() {
   //do something
   eval("b"+"();");
};
```

Now we have to detect the result of string concats. Let's do a couple more of those:

```
function a() {
   //do something
   var d = ["b"];
   eval(d.join("")+"();");
};
```

Still not happy? Let's encode it:

```
function a() {
   //do something
   var d = "YigpOw==";
   eval(atob(d));
};
```

Now, these are some very basic cases, I can complicate them as much as I want. There **really is no way around running the code** - you'd have to run it on every possible input and check and we all know that that's impractical.

#### So what can you do?

Pass dependencies as parameters to the function and use inversion of control. Always be explicit about your more complicated dependencies and not implicit. That way you won't need tools to know what your dependencies are :)

Comment: not just `eval`, but also `window[key]` is much fun. `var keys = Object.keys(window); window[keys[Date.now() % keys.length]]()`. Obfuscated, `(w=window)[(k=Object.keys(w))[Date.now()%k.length]]()`. Have fun.

Comment: To be concise - by impossible I mean: Impossible to get a sound and complete algorithm without checking every possible input to the program.

Comment: Even in static language you can have dynamic dependencies, and eval in this sense is just as bad as reflection. `what functions does a code call`, sounds to me like `does this code call function x`, which sounds like `does this program ever halt` ;P ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use statistical profiler log (`node --prof yourprogram`, v8.log) to calculate 'statistical' call graph. Take a look at log processor source code [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/v8/tools/tickprocessor.js) and [here](https://github.com/sidorares/node-tick)

Answer (score 1):

1. Get code of a function as a string: `a.toString()`
2. Check with RegEx for possible function calls like `possiblefuncname(` and `possiblefuncname.call(` and `possiblefuncname.apply(`
3. Check if `typeof possiblefuncname == 'function'
4. IF 3 is TRUE, Recursively check possiblefuncname for dependencies
5. Set your dependency.

Comment: What about functions which aren't global (i.e. functions inside functions)? Also, how do you hope to get all user-defined global functions in the first place?

Comment: Please see my edits to the answer. Also, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140661/global-variables-for-node-js-standard-modules for your question about the globals.

Comment: How can you recursively check the function? You can't access its scope, and you lose all context when you turn the outer function into a string (where was `a` defined? inside the first nested function, or the other...) In "getting user-defined globals", I meant in the OP's case the functions `a` and `b` (after all, you don't expect someone to manually pass all of his functions).

Comment: In case of a function defined within a function you will get the code of inner function within a string of outer function, and thus all it's inner calls.

Comment: In cases where a function is inherited from private closure, things get much harder, as you now need to get access and parse it's forming closure. You are right. This is nothing short of writing a reflection library for JS.