# NodeJS Require function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was inspecting the global and module of node when I discovered that require was not in them. I don't know if this is magic but if anyone can explain if require is global then why it is not in the global object nor in the module object?

Comment: please visit this link: http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's in *scope*.  When loading in a file, node behind the scenes [wraps](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.16/src/node.js#L878-885) the source code such that your code actually looks like this:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
// here goes what's in your js file
});
```

It then invokes the anonymous function, passing in a fresh object for `exports` and a reference to the `require` function.  ([Further detail here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18317790/201952))

It should now be obvious why you can call `require` even though it's not truly a global.

Comment: this makes sense. I'm going to verify this :) Thanks!

Comment: INTERESTING by wrapping the entire source in an anonymous function things get local only to that and it gives the impression the require is global. Now I understand thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Require is Core Modules compiled into the binary. Read in more detail here http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_core_modules .

The core modules are defined in node's source in the lib/ folder.

Core modules are always preferentially loaded if their identifier is passed to require(). For instance, require('http') will always return the built in HTTP module, even if there is a file by that name.

Comment: This doesn't really address *why* the identifier `require` is defined even though it does not exist in global scope.