# Passing function to Router-Functions module

Tags: node.js, express

Routes.js includes the following lines of code:

```
X = {};
X.xFunction(user) { 
  // some code here 
  // console.log(user.Name);
}       
var Router_Functions = require('/Router_Functions');

app.get('/', Router_Functions.aFunction)
```

Router_Functions.js

```
exports.afunction = function (req, res) {

   xFunction(req.session.user);

}
```

Here, error is `xFunction` is undefined. But in such case, how do you to pass function `X.xFunction()` from 'routes.js' to 'Router_Functions.js'

Comment: possible duplicate of [node.js expose variable to module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474550/node-js-expose-variable-to-module)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I've made a substantial edit. Please review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have something wrong in your architecture. Such an approach is kinda wrong. If you need a function defined in one module to exists in another then you have to export it in separate file. I.e.:

```
// xFunction module
var X = {};
X.xFunction(user) { 
  // some code here 
  // console.log(user.Name);
}
module.exports = X;
```

Then in *Router_Functions.js*

```
exports.afunction = function (req, res) {

   var X= require("xFunction.js");
   X.xFunction(req.session.user);

}
```

If you really want to define the function in *Routes.js* then you have to pass it somehow. For example as a parameter of aFunction

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   Router_Functions.aFunction(req, res, xFunction);
});

// Router_Functions.js
exports.aFunction = function (req, res, xFunction) {
   xFunction(req.session.user);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to pass xFunction while calling aFunction like Router_Functions.aFunction(X.xFunction(user))