# How to Fix ? DeprecationWarning: 'GLOBAL' is deprecated, use 'global'

Tags: node.js

How to fix Depricated warning message `(node:6136) DeprecationWarning: 'GLOBAL' is deprecated, use 'global'`

In my code I have used something like below

```
// initializing globals
GLOBAL.user_session= {};
GLOBAL.config= require('./config/config.js');
```

So how to fix warning message?

Comment: The warning tells you the answer!

Comment: It's not concise.  No question is a dumb question.  It doesn't simply say "Use lowercase global instead of uppercase"... the idea of needing that is slightly odd.  I've been coding for twenty years and give lectures and I figured I'd google it just to make sure... and lo... stack overflow bequeathed an answer that yielded confidence to move forward with my life... now I can sip my coffee in total peace.

Comment: I don't use either and I still get that working...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global variables for node.js standard modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140661/global-variables-for-node-js-standard-modules)

Comment: I'm new to Node (v12.18.3) and I'm getting this warning even though my very simple app.js does not make use of global at all. I'm requiring 'express' (4.17.1), nothing else. How can I debug what is causing this warning?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
global.user_session= {};
global.config= require('./config/config.js');
```