# Are variables defined in the global context accessible when there's name collision?

Tags: node.js, global-variables, scope

If I want to access a variable define in the global context from within a scope where there already exists a variable with the same name:

```
var variable = 'value';
function someScope(variable){
    variable = 'not this';
    var global = Function('return this')();
    console.log('this > ', global.variable);
}
```

Is it possible to still access the global variable somehow?

Neither the `global` object nor [getting the Global object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277182/how-to-get-the-global-object-in-javascript) works. (`global.variable` returns undefined)

Comment: possible duplicate of ['Global' object in node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133114/global-object-in-node-js)

Comment: @feeela & other downvoters, I've changed the question slightly. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variable is really global you can access it via global.name even if there are collisions with a local variable. For example

```
// notice there is not "var" here
variable = 'global';

function someScope() {
    var variable = 'local';
    console.log(variable);            // local
    console.log(global.variable);     // global
}

someScope();
```

However, if you define your variable with "var" at the top of the file (as you have it in your code) then it won't be global and you will get different results (i.e. global.variable will print undefined.)

Answer (score -2):

You can access an global JS variable through the `window` object, as each global variable is a property of the window object:

```
var var1 = 'Hello World!';

// stated on the global scope, is the same as
window.var1 = 'Hello World!';
```

You may also read those globals within a functions scope:

```
function() {
    console.log( window.var1 );
}
```

Comment: shoot, I'm working in node.js (forgot to mention) What would be the equivalent in that?

Comment: Please use a search engine. Stackoverflow is not a web dictionary but a Q&A site…